# How to create an effective WHOIS Script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Disclaimer: I'm a noob to linux and scripting, please don't heckle me.

GOAL: Feed my linux system a .txt file full of IP Addresses and Perform a WHOIS look on each IP and show me specific fields (grep) such as the Organization Field.  Bonus points if someone can help me figure out how to use my API key to check my IP list against abuseipdb.com

I've created an ip.txt file with my IP Addresses and I've tried using the following syntax. I'm using Kali Linux to perform this, but it worked on my friend's Fedora system.

```
sudo for ip in $(cat ip.txt); do whois $ip | echo "$ip $(grep -e 'Organization' | grep -v 'Verizon')"; done > whois.txt
```

My output is: *`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`*. Remove "do" from my command and then I receive *`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'`*

Remove the "done" and the pipe out and then it's just pissed..

Please help a linux n00b :)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Add ip.txt to your question.

Comment: ip.txt is just a list of IP addresses.  unique IP on each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to invoke `sudo` on the command `for ip in $(cat ip.txt)`, and then running the syntactically invalid commands `do whois ...`.  (Note that `for ip in $(cat ip.txt)` is also syntactically invalid, but sudo is never invoked so no shell ever tries to parse that string as a command).  You need to narrow the scope of sudo.  eg

```
while read ip; do sudo whois "$ip" | ... ; done > whois.txt < ip.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I also echo the variable? ($ip) with my output?

I tried to use 

"while read -r ip; do sudo whois "$ip" | echo "$ip" | grep Organization; done > whois.txt < ip.txt"

Comment: @VOIPSec You can do `sudo whois "$ip" | { echo "$ip"; grep ... ; }`